# Points in a rectangular configuration define equal metric segments?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. For points $x,y \in X$ we define the **metric segment** between them as the following set:

$$\left [ x,y \right ] =  \left \{ z \in X : d(x,z)+d(z,y)=d(x,y)\right \}$$

We will say that a quadruplet of points $x,y,x',y' \in X$ is in a **rectangular configuration** if it holds that $d(x,y)=d(x',y')$, $d(x,y')=d(x',y)$ and $d(x,x')=d(y,y')$.

Assume $x,y \in X$ are points in a metric space $(X,d)$. Let $x',y' \in \left [ x,y \right ]$. My question is *does $x,y,x',y'$ being in a rectangular configuration imply $\left [ x,y \right ]=\left [ x',y' \right ]$*?

It seems highly improbable to me. However, I cannot seem to find a counterexample.

**Note**: The term rectangular configuration comes from the fact that any two pairs of corresponding sides of a rectangle are of equal length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$X=\{x,x',y,y',z\}$, and $d$ defined by $$d(x,y)=d(x',y')=2,\; d(x,x')=d(y,y')=1,\; d(x,y')=d(x',y)=1,\;$$
$$d(x,z)=d(y,z)=1.5,\; d(x',z)=d(y',z)=1.$$ Then $z\in [x',y'], z\notin [x,y]$.

Comment: A nice counterexample. Thank you!